# How to get container dimension?

Tags: flash-cs6, createjs

How to get width and height of a movieClip in createjs?

What I am doing is creating a shape, then convert to movieClip, and give it a name, I can access the instance using the name in js, but I can't get the width and height?

Is there any idea or way to achieve this?
I've noticed that createJS extension for Flash CS6, converts the movieClip I did into container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All library items exported from Flash CC have a `nominalBounds`, which is an EaselJS Rectangle (x,y,width,height).

```
(lib.test = function() {
    this.initialize();

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#339900").s().p("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");
    this.shape.setTransform(114.6,81.5);

    this.addChild(this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,229.3,163);

var instance = new lib.test();
console.log(instance.nominalBounds);
```

You can also use the `getBounds()` method, which has some limitations with shapes, but considers the objects transform (and sub-objects as well).

- Initial Post: http://blog.createjs.com/width-height-in-easeljs/
- Follow-up: http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/

Comment: What about items exported from Flash CS6? can I use nominalBounds too?

Comment: Objects exported from Flash CC will have nominal bounds properties, as shown above.

Comment: isn't there any chance to use nominal bounds properties from flash cs6?

Comment: @SamirSabri Yes. You can use nominal bounds. I don't know if `getBounds` considers it though when checking a container that has a CS6-exported symbol in it.